# What is an easier way to iterate over nested lists in python?

Tags: python, nested

Suppose I have a list like the one below and I am trying to iterate over `nested_list[i][1]` elements and return a boolean

```
nested_list = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9]]

print 1 in (nested_list[i][1] for i in range(nested_list))
```

I am still a newbie in Python, so someone with more experience tell me please: is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
print 1 in (i[1] for i in nested_list)
```

If you only want to check for membership, I would suggest that you do indeed use `(...)` instead of `[...]` because the latter would create the *entire* list when there is really no need to do so.

Comment: Thanks this is so much easier than using the len() function

Comment: With `[...]` you create the entire list, but with `(...)` you don't, you just create a 'generator' that can be iterated over (without calculating each value before-hand), which is more efficient in this case. Try `print (i[1] for i in nested_list)` and `print [i[1] for i in nested_list]`.

Answer (score 2):

A.R.S has already suggested a good solution, but an alternative answer is simply `any(i[1] == 1 for i in nested_list)`.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, too. But I have to say I also liked A.R.S's better. Thanks anyways

Comment: @mehmettekn: I think this answer is the way to go.  The `x in <generator_expression>` pattern is a bit too convluted.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(nested_list)
>>> a[:,1]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> 1 in a[:,1]
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for (x,y) in nested_list:print y
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer using **itertools** will shortcircuit at the first hit too.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> 
>>> 1 in (imap(itemgetter(1), nested_list))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me just add this one.

```
print(1 in zip(*nested_list)[1])
```